# How to use hexcodes to correctly show the right values in php?

Tags: php, laravel

Struggling to get my head around this one, and I find it quite tricky to explain so will do my best.

What I am trying to do is use a number to show allergens in foods. So for example an entry in the database could be "falafel" which has an allergen code of 16448 that is currently stored in the database.

What I need to do is take this number and convert it to hex, which gives me 4040.

I have this array of allergens

```
    $allergens = array(
      "celery"      => array("label" => "Celery",      "short" => "", "value" => 0x00000001),
      "crustaceans" => array("label" => "Crustaceans", "short" => "", "value" => 0x00000002),
      "eggs"        => array("label" => "Eggs",        "short" => "", "value" => 0x00000010),
      "fish"        => array("label" => "Fish",        "short" => "", "value" => 0x00000020),
      "gluten"      => array("label" => "Gluten",      "short" => "", "value" => 0x00000040),
      "lupin"       => array("label" => "Lupin",       "short" => "", "value" => 0x00000080),
      "milk"        => array("label" => "Milk",        "short" => "", "value" => 0x00000100),
      "molluscs"    => array("label" => "Molluscs",    "short" => "", "value" => 0x00000200),
      "mustard"     => array("label" => "Mustard",     "short" => "", "value" => 0x00000400),
      "nuts"        => array("label" => "Nuts",        "short" => "", "value" => 0x00001000),
      "peanuts"     => array("label" => "Peanuts",     "short" => "", "value" => 0x00002000),
      "sesame"      => array("label" => "Sesame",      "short" => "", "value" => 0x00004000),
      "soya"        => array("label" => "Soya",        "short" => "", "value" => 0x00008000),
      "sulphur"     => array("label" => "Sulphur",     "short" => "", "value" => 0x00010000),
    );
```

I then need to go through here, and see where 4040 matches. So in this case it would be gluten (40), and sesame (4000).

Another example would be a dish that has an allergens code of 320. Converted to hex this is 800. So I would need to return the labels for values of 400, 200, 100, 80, and 20 from the above array.

The numbers in the DB I cannot change. The array I posted above was in code that was previously used in the website that is no longer working.

Another example is something in the DB has 96 as it's allergens code. Which in hex is 60, which can be made of 40 and 20 from the array which makes sense given this food. I know the values in the table are not in hex. But I need to convert them to hex, and then with this hex number find how it can be made from the numbers in the array and return the labels based on these numbers

How can I achieve this? Hopefully my explanation makes sense.

Comment: The logic is not exactly clear. `40` in `4040` could be explained with "match anywhere", but how exactly are `4040` and `4000` supposed to "match"?

Comment: Why must the value be in hex? It will consume less space in the db as an integer, and you also gain benefit since you obviously dont read in hex too well. (nor does the average person).

Comment: This is just the way it has been done before. In the DB it is stored as an int, so in the example above it is 16448

Comment: So it is your belief that converting to hex (which is 1 to 1 by the way) somehow creates new information that you will be able to search among for patterns that will reveal related classifications? ... This simply isnt true. Hex does not create magic.

Comment: But if the base 10 values *already* have classification ranges, or some kind of system in their assignment of values to allergens, then yes the hex will carry over to a detectible pattern. .... **What are the base 10 classification ranges for these values?**

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this and simply don't understand it. What I know is this is how it was done before, and I need to somehow get it working again.
Another example would be a food item with the allergens code of 320. So in hex this is 800. And in my array it should then return the values for 400, 200, 100, 80, and 20. Does that make sense?

Comment: "I'm sorry I'm new to this and simply don't understand it" ... How do you expect to solve a problem you dont understand? How do you expect to get help if you dont know the requirements?

Comment: I know what I am trying to achieve, but I just don't know how to do it. I know it was once done this way too so should be possible. I'm trying to figure out how to do it in my example above

Comment: "I know what I am trying to achieve" ... Could you share these insights in your question? If all you want to do is convert an integer to hex, then a quick internet search will reveal how. Search "convert int to hex in php". But if you expect to gain meaning from these hex values then please share what meaning a human can get from them first.

Comment: Okay I've added another example to my original question. I am trying to return label values based on the hex number I have.

Comment: Im afraid "Another example would be a dish that has an allergens code of 320. Converted to hex this is 800. So I would need to return the labels for values of 400, 200, 100, 80, and 20 from the above array." ... offers no clarification. It still demonstrates no pattern. I could guess and suppose that those values are factors, but there are other factors. And you fail to state whether the labels are in hex as well.

Comment: The labels are strings as shown in the above array. The pattern is to take the hexnumber (of example 4040) and match it to the values in the array, so it would be to return the label for 4000 and the label for 40

Comment: You also have a complete misunderstanding of what hex is. How do you expect to factor a hex value (while pretending its a base 10 integer) with letters in it? What would your deduction be for a hex value such as FF.

Comment: Then how does "200, 100, 80, and 20" match? You mentioned those as well.

Comment: I think because the numbers stored in the DB can only be converted to numbers that will match the pattern of hexnumbers in the above array.
What I mean in that example is that the value of 800 is created by adding up 400, 200, 100, 80, and 20. So because it is created using these numbers, I need to show the labels associated with the numbers

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve my above problem then. The numbers in the DB I cannot change. 
The array I posted above was in code that was previously used in the website that is no longer working.

Another example is something in the DB has 96 as it's allergens code. Which in hex is 60, which can be made of 40 and 20 from the array which makes sense given this food.

I know the values in the table are not in hex. But I need to convert them to hex, and then with this hex number find how it can be made from the numbers in the array I posted

Comment: Ok. I'm seeing a pattern now, slightly. From your last explanation. ... Perhaps update your question with the text from your last comment(s) so that it stands out.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You said "Another example would be a food item with the allergens code of 320. So in hex this is 800" ... But 320 in hex is 140. ... Any explanation on what you think it should be?

Comment: Ah this was my mistake. I converted it wrong. You're right, it is 140. So in this case it would need to return the labels for 100 (milk) and 40 (gluten) from the array

Comment: 100 + 30 adds to 130 not 140. How do you explain this new logic?

Comment: Sorry, typo. 40 not 30, have edited comment

Comment: Edit your question/post, not just the comments. Not everyone reads the entire comment discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to make it work. I pass in the number from the DB and array of allergens to this function -

```
static function findMatchingLabels($number, $allergens)
  {
    $hexNumber = dechex($number);
    $matchingLabels = array();

    foreach ($allergens as $allergen) {
      if ($allergen['value'] & hexdec($hexNumber)) {
        $matchingLabels[] = $allergen['label'];
      }
    }

    return $matchingLabels;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

(@sunnyj58 In continuation from our discussion in comments)

The values in the table represent a bitmask as first alluded to by @shingo in comments.

The "bitmask system" revealed from your table uses 14 of the bits in a 16-bit integer (unsigned).

The allergen themselves are like checkboxes (bits).

```
Hex(Base16)  Base10        Allergen
-----------  ------        --------
0x00000001        1        Celery
0x00000002        2        Crustaceans
0x00000010       16        Eggs
0x00000020       32        Fish
0x00000040       64        Gluten
0x00000080      128        Lupin
0x00000100      256        Milk
0x00000200      512        Molluscs
0x00000400     1024        Mustard
0x00001000     4096        Nuts
0x00002000     8192        Peanuts
0x00004000    16384        Sesame
0x00008000    32768        Soya
0x00010000    65536        Sulphur
```

Using this table as a guide I will present a solution which will intrinsically infer an algorithm. However I wont be using hexadecimal to present the solution, though you can later if you find it easier to work with.

```
Input: 

"falafel" which has an allergen code of 16448

Algorithm:

is 16448 >= 65546? no
is 16488 >= 32768? no
is 16488 >= 16384? yes --> Sesame
  Find the difference: subtract 16384 from 16488 = 104
is 104 >= 8192? no
is 104 >= 4096? no
is 104 >= 1024? no
if 104 >= 512? no
is 104 >= 256? no
is 104 >= 128? no
is 104 >= 64? yes --> Gluten
  Find the difference: subtract 64 from 104 = 40
is 40 >= 32? yes --> Fish
  Find the difference: subtract 32 from 40 = 8
is 8 >= 16? no
is 8 >= 2? yes --> Crustaceans
  Find the difference: subtract 2 from 8 = 6
is 6 >= 1? yes --> Celery

Output:

Sesame, Gluten, Fish, Crustaceans, Celery
```

See if you can transform this into code. I'll have to come back to this answer to update it with code later. (out of time).